# How to add Effects/Filters to image iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i want to add effects for image as shown in attached image[image]

i don't have any idea how to do this.

can any of you let me know.

Comment: get RGBA pixel data from image and make any changes you need: change color, move pixels etc. You can easely find this code here, on stack overflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check this git..
code is provided..so this will help you the most..

https://github.com/OmidH/Filtrr

Answer (score 4):

you can try [OpenCv](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) for Image Processing.. [Here](http://computer-vision-talks.com/2011/01/using-opencv-in-objective-c-code/) you can find the tutorial for image effects..

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [NYXImagesKit](https://github.com/Nyx0uf/NYXImagesKit).

Comment: Can this be used in a commercial application?

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

try this code it will help you more