# Photo effects like instagram

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, uiimage, instagram

In my iphone app user can take images,after taking the image how to give effects to that image like instagram

Is there any good tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use a third party API like [Aviary](http://www.aviary.com/ios) or the library in [Rocks' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15157065/840428).

If you want to write the logic yourself, you'll need to to process the images using Core Image. In addition to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html), a good place to start is [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5689/beginning-core-image-in-ios-5) from Ray Wenderlich's blog. Lisa Bettany also wrote a while back about [how they created filters in Camera+](http://taptaptap.com/blog/creating-a-camera-plus-fx/).

Answer (score 1):

Check out this tutorial from raywenderlich: [beginning-core-image-in-ios-5](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5689/beginning-core-image-in-ios-5). It is part of another tutorial on the site which tells you [how-to-create-an-app-like-instagram-with-a-web-service-backend](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13511/how-to-create-an-app-like-instagram-with-a-web-service-backend-part-12).

**beginning-core-image-in-ios-5:**

> "Core Image is a powerful framework that lets you easily apply filters
>   to images, such as modifying the vibrance, hue, or exposure. It uses
>   the GPU (or CPU, user definable) to process the image data and is very
>   fast. Fast enough to do real time processing of video frames!
>
> Core Image filters can stacked together to apply multiple effects to
>   an image or video frame at once. When multiple filters are stacked
>   together they are efficient because they create a modified single
>   filter that is applied to the image, instead of processing the image
>   through each filter, one at a time.
>
> ...
>
> In this tutorial, you will get hands-on experience playing around with
>   Core Image. We’ll apply a few different filters, and you’ll see how
>   easy it is to apply cool effects to images in real time!"

Having read through this tutorial, you will no doubt get the result you want and learn a whole lot too!

In addition to that, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9580368/1359306) has many answers - some of which may be very useful to you. This seems like a very popular task and so researching all of the many options is key. Good luck.